# Is "Technical skills precisely" appropriate for a list of specific technical knowledge on résumé

Tags: phrase-requests

If I am going to put the list of specific technical knowledge on a résumé, is it appropriate to use the term "Technical skills precisely", or is there a more appropriate term to use?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: to tell my knowledge and skill in a very specific ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Technical Skills in Detail". (As contrasted with "Overview of Technical Skills"). Other options, which I feel are less natural, include

- Detail of Technical Skills
- Detailed Technical Skills
- Technical Skills (Expanded)

vs

- Technical Skills in Overview
- Summary of Technical Skills
- Technical Skills (Summarised)

Answer (score 4):

The general form [noun phrase] [adverb] even for the title of a section, is really bizarre (unidiomatic, ungrammatical) English.

If you *must* say that your list is somehow 'precise', you would say 'Precise Technical Skills'. But pragmatically that is somewhat redundant, and context will remove any ambiguity. Are you trying to distinguish from *general* technical skills?

Stick with just 'Technical Skills'; your following list will be precise or specific enough.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a heading for your list, *Technical Skills* alone should suffice. You can specify your knowledge level for each item.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for *relevant technical skills*.

Comment: not actually, The information is relevant but it is more descriptive detail to give the idea what i'am really know for example what feature on asp.net that i have been working on.